# Uknown ?? in symfony's public/index.php?

Tags: php

While I was looking over symfony's `public/index.php` I came across the following snippet of code:

```
$env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev';
$debug = (bool) ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== $env));
```

Therefore I performed the following searches:

- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+%3F%3F&t=canonical&ia=web
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+%24var+%3F%3F+%24var2&t=canonical&ia=qa
- https://secure.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%3F%3F&scope=quickref

But still I cannot figure out what the operator `??` actually means. Can you provide me info regarding this operator/syntax ?

Comment: it's a PHP 7+ exclusive ternary operator (aka: Null Coalescing Operator) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's shortest version of

```
$env = isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] : 'dev';
```

was added in PHP 7